# navigation overlapping

Tags: html, css

On this page: http://wilwaldon.com/crossing/badnav.html

notice: the left navigation where it states "A 4 really long page title. And another long title. about half way down the menu. It exceeds the width of the navigation and goes onto the content area.

I've tried for about 3 hours to fix this, I'm sure it's just me being overworked and stressed out but I can't figure this out for the life of me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the desired behavior, exactly?

Comment: I want the "A 4 really long page title. And another long title." To stay within the green area of the navigation.

Thank you, much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Just get rid of all the `width`s and extra `padding-right` on the list items and anchor tags and it'll sort itself out.

The width of the list items is already being constrained by the width of `#leftnav`, so setting widths on the list items just makes them go *wider* than you want rather than narrower because of the added indentation. Without the width they just fill out whatever space they have available.